In this movie, master and apprentice were playing the finale of a TH poker tournament, and apprentice intentionally mucks a winning hand at the end
This movie is about poker. I watched just the end part with a friend who explained what was going.
The two finalists of a presumably major Texas Hold'em tornament knew each other and were perhaps master and apprentice. It seemed it was the last tournament the master would play. The last hand, which decided the tornament winner, gave a Full House to the master. IIRC the involved cards were aces and 3s. The apprentice though a bit and mucked his hand, giving his master's hand the victory.
Once the prizes were given and tournament ended, the master had a small -IIRC- motivational talk with the apprentice.
The exact ending scene shows the apprentice reminding what hand he mucked. From an upward camera angle, as if the camera was in the table itself, you see that the mucked hands were a pair of aces, which could make the apprentice win, perhaps with four aces or a bigger Full House (giving the hidden message that he intentionally lost just for respect to this master).
I have no other hints regarding the movie. I watched it just once, and don't remember the actors. Just the language: english (which does not bring so much clues).

Sounds like  Lucky You
From Wikipedia's summary

He and his father both advance to the final table of nine. Billie looks on from the audience as Huck and L.C. have a showdown. Huck deliberately folds a winning hand, going out in third place.

The two actors are Eric Bana and Robert Duvall

This is an image from the scene you decribed

I can't find the scene online but here's the movie trailer



